# Laravel 5.3 Auth:user(): logged in as guest instead of user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using laravel 5.3, and using Hesto/multi-auth package. 
All my home.blade is working fine, in my nav bar it returns the current login user. But everytime I created a new view, and extend my nav bar to it my nav bar shows "LOGIN REGISTER" instead of username even though I'm already logged in.

So, when I'm in home.blade I successfully logged in as a user, but when I navigate to another view, I am read as a guest.
As a sample, I experimenting my welcome.blade.

This is my route for one of my user.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'customer', 'middleware' => 'customer'], function () {


Route::model( 'customer' , 'App\Customer' );
  Route::get('/login', 'CustomerAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
  Route::post('/login', 'CustomerAuth\LoginController@login');
  Route::post('/logout', 'CustomerAuth\LoginController@logout');

    Route::get('registration_form', function()
    {
        return view('customer/auth/registration_form');
    });
    Route::post("register_customer", 'CustomerAuth\RegisterController@register');

  Route::post('/password/email', 

'CustomerAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
      Route::post('/password/reset', 'CustomerAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
      Route::get('/password/reset', 'CustomerAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
      Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'CustomerAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
    });
```

My kernel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'business' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotBusiness::class,
        'business.guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfBusiness::class,
        'customer' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotCustomer::class,
        'customer.guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfCustomer::class,
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
```

Controller

public function showWelcome(Customer $customer)
    {
         return view('welcome');
}

```
public function showWelcome(Customer $customer)
    {
         return view('welcome');
}


  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('customer');
    }

     protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('customer');
```

This is the customer.php in routes folder

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    $users[] = Auth::user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard()->user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard('customer')->user();

    //dd($users);

    return view('customer.home');

})->name('home');
```

Part of nav bar

```
 @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/customer/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/customer/registration_form') }}">Register</a></li>

                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ url('/customer/logout') }}"
                                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        Logout
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/customer/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if user is loggedIn use `Auth::check()`.

Try this is your view

```
@if(Auth::check())
    //user loggedIn
    {!! auth()->user()->username !!}
@else
    Guest User
@endif
```

Comment: what is your username column name in users table?

Comment: I added the else part,it return as Guest user. I'm using {!! auth()->user()->name !!}

Comment: Are you sure? You are loggedIn?

Comment: Yes. I am logged in my /customer/home, but when I'm in welcome.blade, I am guest. I extend my nav bar to welcome.blade. I know I'm missing something, but I can't still figured it out.

Comment: did you checked the welcome.blade if it extends the correct navbar.blade?

Comment: it calls the right navbar. I have 3 userss  and every nav bar has the same code

Answer (score 0):

Since you used hesto/multi-auth package and generated an auth for customer model, you need to check this by using guard like this in your if condition.

```
Auth::guard('customer')->check()
```

It's the same for any auth you make, example `Auth::guard('business')->check()`

and to get the user model of that particular guard you'll use

```
Auth::guard('customer')->user()
```

For accessing name

```
Auth::guard('customer')->user()->name
```